# DCVS and Bug Database

Tags: project-management, version-control, issue-tracking

I am considering implementing the following policy and would like to run it by the community before implementing it:

All mercurial commits must have a bug id corresponding to our bug reporting database.

All commits immediately preceding a push for a new feature must have a bug id (it's a new feature but the id is still a "bug id" in the database)

This will do several things. First, it will ensure that an entry is always put into the bug database for all code changes. Second, it will provide a diff of each change made for each bug fix. This would also simplify commenting in the mercurial commits and put most details about the commit into the bug report.

Do you know of any reasons why this would be a bad idea? Also, do you think I should make some additions to this policy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely do **not** want to enforce this policy on **all commits**.  One advantage of DVCS is that developers can commit and promote changes to private branches at any time.  It's a reasonable policy for commits to production code in the central repository.

Comment: +1 for pointing out this is only useful on a subset of commits.

Comment: I like this. My intention is for this to only be done for the central repository. However, the way we have this setup is everyone is supposed to push their bug fixes and new features to the central repo as soon as they are done. Are you recommending that they have their own branches, then do a merge into a another wc, then commit that merge with the bug id before pushing?

Comment: @JonathanHenson: Certainly they should work on their own branches, and commit as often as they like.  Before pushing, presumably they should merge with current production code and retest.  Only now is the change "done", and ready to push.

Comment: We enforce commits with comment string matching a tracking ID.  For private branches, the dev is able to raise a ticket if they want, or use a place holder we have allocated specifically for untracked changes. A push to the master repo rejects the placeholder as well any that do not have a valid ticket. (We use GIT, but the workflow is the same) 
The idea of the "all commits" is it creates a good habit/no exceptions policy (easy to implement and explain).

Comment: -1 I'm sorry but this is not the case, commits cannot be renamed in mercurial (without a large amount of work), so any commit that will ever be pushed into the main branch should have a case number attached, regardless of whether it's in a "private" branch. If you've got work DVCS workflow correct you don't ever commit directly onto a production repo, you should push to it.

Comment: @EdWoodcock - RTFM! "Renaming commits", which is really **editing commit message**, *can* be done easy - use Histedit if MQ seems as overkill. In case of feature-per-task policy only **mergeset** to default can hold ticket-id and passing CS on push is a task of hook, **which can be done**

Comment: @LazyBadger RTFC (comment), I said "without a large amount of work", and I am including plugins and the mq extension in this "work". You can do it in a raw hg repo by directly editing the patch history, but this is very dangerous in terms of synchronisation between branches. Changesets in a standard mercurial repo are immutable, and should remain that way.

Comment: @EdWoodcock - add and use HistEdit isn't "lange amount of work", just some minutes. I **done** it

Comment: @LazyBadger ... and the other minutes required to explain what it is and why we need it to my manager; then the minutes required to explain why it is, why we need it and how to use it to my team; then the minutes needed to synchronise all the branches whenever anyone reorders the history (we normally have upwards of 30 feature branches per project at any one time, so that might take a while).

Answer (score 1):

We do this where I work (in theory).

It's genuinely really helpful when people do it right, as you can go into the cases in our particular bug-tracker-of-choice and see that you're getting the right changesets for a particular release based on the case IDs of the features you're adding. Your point about keeping the comments on the case is another plus, as in my experience *no-one will read your commit messages*.

However, it's a pain when people either *put the wrong case ID on* or *just plain don't bother*, so I'd say if you're going to do it make sure you have a staging repo where you're able to change the case ID before you push it into your trunk, and add a policy to the remote end to reject changesets without a case ID on them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Documenting **all changes** in form of tickets is, in common, good style
2. Direct links ticket-changesets is good

But

1. Some changeset may be indirectly related to issue (1-st CS - changes for ticket, 2-nd+ - fixes for CS 1)
2. Flat history with only commit-messages doesn't provide nice interface for filtering **from VCS-side**
3. Branch-per-feature workflow hide side-effects of 1 and 2 and make marking **all** changesets obsolete even from issue-tracker side - referenced maybe only first and last commit

Comment: What then would you recommend as modification of the policy?

Comment: @JonathanHenson - as usual, "it depends"... From habits, team culture, workflow, even used VCS and client-tools. For flat history in [one my project](http://www.assembla.com/code/customlocations-greylink/subversion/changesets) I use ticket-id relation in commit-messages (where it applicable), in [another](http://www.assembla.com/code/seeker/mercurial/changesets) I have 2 separate branches for different tasks and branch-name only is enough for orientation. Right choice is your personal headache as PM, colleague

Answer (score 0):

People do not look in bug databases to see code diffs for bugs.  They look in version control.  Therefore, it makes sense to require a bug id for the last commit that fixes a bug, so you can make a note in the bug tracker and identify what build bug fixes are in, but every single commit is overkill.

If people are committing features you don't want, you have a whole other problem, and probably need some sort of gatekeeper workflow.  I'd highly recommend you look into more integrated solutions like kiln or bitbucket.

Comment: I agree, the idea is for devs to be able to look in the VC for diffs and see the entire history for the bug in the issue tracking if they need to know what the commit was for--not the other way around. Also, while a team is looking at a bug in the tracker that has been marked as resolved, another dev, or project admin could look and easily find the changes for the bug fix.

Comment: Lots of people look in bug databases for code diffs.  It's the reason that every non-distributed VCS has some form of this feature, whether baked in or added on.

Answer (score -3):

The more obstacles you put in the way of me committing, the less often I'll commit.  That really defeats the point of a DVCS.

You're really trying to solve a symptom with this approach rather than trying to fix the root cause.  You have a team of developers who:

- Don't understand the value of the bug tracker;
- Don't seem to communicate very well, and repeat work that other developers have already done;
- Veer off-task and write code that hasn't been discussed and hasn't been authorised.

You *could* enforce this policy.  However, if the developers are already dysfunctional, what is this policy really going to achieve?  Is it suddenly going to give you a focused, communicative team who maintain an excellent set of bug reports?

No.  It will give you an awful lot of bug fixes checked in against the wrong bug report.

You need to address the issues in your team by *managing them*.  Show them how they are stepping on each other's toes.  Hold daily standup meetings so that Bob can tell the team that he's fixing bug X so that Dave won't start work on the same thing.  Explain the value of the bug tracker.  If your developers come to see that what you're trying to achieve is a good thing they'll do it automatically.

Comment: But, suppose I didn't want people committing code that isn't a bug fix or a feature we talked about adding. I am growing tired of miscellaneous "new features" being added because someone thought it would be good that then causes a bug. If they don't push, they can do what the hell they want with the code. If someone wants to add a new feature, the team as a whole needs to be consulted--especially the architect.

Comment: Anyways, part of the point is, the bug tracking database is not getting updated and I want to have someway to force it to be.

Comment: Suppose I'm fixing bug 12345 and spot another bug.  I can either a) take 15 minutes out to commit what I'm doing, open the bug tracker, create a new bug report, fix the bug, commit and go back to bug 12345, b) commit to bug 12345, commit a fix for the other bug and not log it, and go back to bug 12345, c) fix the bug silently and commit when 12345 is fixed, or d) ignore the bug.  You want me to do a. I want to do b. If I'm forced to commit I'll do c or d. Breaking the commit process isn't a good way to fix a broken bug tracking process. You'll have two broken processes and an unhappy team.

Comment: @JonathanHenson - managing and using issue-tracker is another story (of weak management)

Comment: @Ant - nobody interested in that you *want*. You get money for job, which you **must to do** according to *defined rules**. Setup your rules at own home, not at work

Comment: @LazyBadger This is a small company and I am the project lead and unfortunately, there is no one else to do the management. That is why I am trying to come up with a way to enforce some sort of standard.

Comment: @Ant, option d.) would cost you your job if I found out about it. Option c.) would be fine in moderation.

Comment: @Ant - option b) would cost you your job if I found out about it

Comment: option b would cause another developer a lost hour or so of productivity when they went to fix a bug that had already been fixed by someone who didn't log it.

Comment: @JonathanHenson - I guessed it. But "Do Thing Right" rule say (me): you have to have more actions in order to convert chaos to Ordnung, because you have to presume the prevalence of "Ants" in devs

Comment: Here's what I'd prefer my workflow to be.  I work on bug 12345.  I spot another bug.  I commit.  I fix the other bug and enter a descriptive commit message.  I fix bug 12345.  I commit.  I look at my commit logs since the last push.  I enter any bugs I fixed that are not attached to a bug number into the bug tracker and close them.  With this workflow, I don't context switch from coding to admin until I'm ready to push, which is itself an admin task.  You guys really care more about pretty reports than developer productivity?  *Really?* (Unless you have the lowest-friction bug tracker ever...)

Comment: Thinking about it, what I'd probably do is option e: Stick a TODO comment above the other bug and come back to it later, bug-commit-enforcement or not.

Comment: @Ant, Here would be my, I think reasonable response to that: Put a TODO comment over the bug. Carry on working on what you are doing and commit your changes. Then report the bug in the bug tracker, then fix it, then commit. There is no productivity lost other than the basic overhead of keeping organized. Second, I care deeply about productivity. That is my entire motive. However, one developer caring only about their own productivity at the expense of everyone else's is not an asset to a team but a detriment to everyone.

Comment: Sounds very reasonable.  However, I'd be interested to know *why* the developers aren't using the bug tracker.  I once campaigned to get FogBugz in place at a company I worked for.  It was enormously popular.  They then switched to TFS and, despite having a "commits must be attached to a bug" policy, nobody used the bug tracker.  They ticked the "ignore policy" box instead.  The reasons were pretty simple: TFS is an appallingly bad bug tracker.  It is incredibly slow and the UI is dreadful.  Instead of forcing people to use your tracker, why not ask them why they don't?

Comment: @Ant, they don't because we haven't put a policy forward asking them to in any organized fasion. Also, in my experience, when people are given a choice, they procrastinate such actions and think about their own productivity over the productivity of the whole team.

Comment: -1 This attitude is terrible. Repeat after me: "You are not a beautiful and unique snowflake. You are the same decaying organic matter as everyone else.".

Comment: @Ed Woodcock: Personally, I think the attitude that all developers are lazy bums who won't use tools to improve their team's efficiency unless they are forced to is terrible.  What's worse is the fact that the question asker is planning to enforce this policy based not on any actual evidence that his team are lazy bums; just that he's jaded and cynical enough to believe this of everyone.  I think educating the team and communicating more effectively are better than putting up roadblocks in the development process.

Comment: @Ant Agreed, not all developers are lazy. However, in my experience, a reasonably high proportion are, and quite a few of the rest are fairly forgetful. At the end of the day a policy like this is not detrimental if you're handling your bug- and feature-tracking "properly" (as defined by the OP). I agree it would be best if everyone agreed to do something like this and did it of their own volition, but it's generally difficult to get this kind of approach to work, even in small teams (my team is 9 people and people will often agree to something then not do it).

Comment: @Ant, there is a big difference between calling someone a lazy bum (which I never did) and being realistic about human nature. Furthermore, I have plenty of evidence. The bug tracker has been up for years and I keep it up to date. Anyways, what is the difference between a project lead "educating a team and communicating more effectively" and coming up with a policy for people to use? If you are on a team and you repeatedly do the exact opposite of what he/she asks, you will not be on the team very long. It doesn't really matter if it is an "enforced" policy or not--it is the same thing.

Comment: @Ant, I am not trying to harm anyone's productivity but to foster a culture where collaboration is organized and useful instead of chaotic. You don't do that without policies--enforced or voted on or whatever. We live by using agreed upon conventions. I don't see the difference between what I am suggesting and coding conventions or anything else. We work together by coming to organized workflows.

Comment: @Jonathan: Very good points.  However, I still feel that policies are often band-aids for dysfunctional teams, and that the need for this policy suggests larger problems.  The only way you'll really know what will happen will be to implement the policy and see.

Comment: @Ant if a team is dysfunctional, then it is because:
a. communication is poor
b. Team members don't cooperate
c. Or there just isn't an organized workflow between team members.

I know the team and a.) and b.) aren't the case. Even if they are, cooperation can be forced by telling people suck it up and do their job regardless of if they like it or by sacking them. There is absolutely no excuse for b.) and that is why this is an important factor to consider in hiring someone. 

c.) is in need of an organized convention, call it what you will: policy or  an anarcho-syndicalist commune.

Comment: @Jonathan: Help, help, I'm being oppressed!

Comment: Please refrain from lengthy discussions in comments.  If you feel the need to discuss this further please do so in Chat.